# paste giving infinite number of header lines in output

Tags: unix, paste

I'm trying to horizontally concatenate 300 tab-delimited txt files, each about 800 kb, all in the same directory.  Each has a header row, followed by 22k rows of numbers.  When I try

```
paste -d '\t' *.txt > out.txt
```

the command hangs until I abort it -- after 30 min, the output file was 33 gb (total should be < 300 mb), consisting only of the header row repeated many times.  Any idea what's going on?

Thanks very much.

HBF

Comment: Since `*.txt` matches `out.txt`, paste will be reading that file and then writing to it and then reading what it just wrote to it, etc. This could lead to the feedback loop you're seeing. Try removing `out.txt` and direct paste's output to a file whose name does not end in `.txt` and see if there is still a problem.